# How does two-way communication with sockets work?

Tags: sockets

I am getting started with socket programming in C#. I looked at a couple of example programs which open a socket, get one stream from the socket and use the same stream to both read data from the client and write data to the client. How does this exactly work? I had thought that there would have to be two separate streams - one for the server to read and one for it to write. How does the socket distinguish between data that is to be read by the server and data written by the server?

Comment: What protocol are you looking into for sockets - UDP or TCP ?

Comment: @JSinh As the answer is the same for both, your question is pointless.

Comment: @user207421 that is not true at all and please don't assume the intent of my question

Answer (score 3):

Internally there are two buffers - incoming data that you can read, and outgoing data that you have written. You drain the first buffer, and the implementation re-fills it by reading from the socket. You push your data into the second buffer, and the implementation drains it by writing to the socket.

Comment: The code looks like this: <br>  Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc); 
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s); <br> We are creating a reader and a writer out of the same stream...how are the two buffers differentiated?

Comment: As I said, internally. When you write to the stream, output buffer is used. When you try to read from the stream, the bytes are coming from the input buffer.